# How to get View object to respond to changes to its data source

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, model-view

Say I have a CatModel object:

```
@interface CatModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *catImage;

- (void)addWhisker:(Whisker*)whisker;
```

And I have a CatView:

```
@interface CatView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) CatModel *dataSource;

@end
```

I want the CatView to automatically add a whisker image when it detects that a whisker was added to its dataSource. I don't want to add a Whisker to the CatModel instance and also add an addWhisker method to the CatView. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you're wanting CatView to observer CatModel: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html

Or, you can use Protocols / delegates, and let them know when a whisker is added.

Or, you can use NSNotifications to let subscribers know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you may use **key-value observing**, but unfortunately, `NSArray` or any other collections are not KVO-compatible.

Instead, you may wish to create a delegate functionality:

```
@protocol CatModelObserving

@optional

- (void)catModel:(CatModel *)model didAddWhisker:(Whisker *)whisker;

@end

...  

@interface CatModel


@property (weak, nonatomic) id <CatModelObserving> observer;

@end
```

Then you would ensure that the `CatView` conforms to that protocol and implements that method:

```
- (void)catModel:(CatModel *)model didAddWhisker:(Whisker *)whisker {
    // handle it properly
}
```

In your `CatModel.m`, inside the `-addWhisker:` method you should notify the observer that a whisker has been added:

```
if (self.observer && [self.observer respondsToSelector:@selector(catModel:didAddWhisker:)]) {
    [self.observer catModel:self didAddWhisker:whisker];
}
```

If you wish to have multiple "observers", you may consider using GCD and block-based "notifications", like so:

```
[catModel addDidAddWhiskerBlock:^(Whisker *whisker) {
    // handle it properly
}];
```

But I will not discuss that method in this answer. As a hint I can suggest using `NSMutableArray` storing all those blocks, then iteratiating through those blocks in the `-addWhisker:` method and calling each block.